# FFMPEG - build ubuntu 32 bit - missing shared library : libspeex

Tags: build, ffmpeg, cross-platform, static-libraries

I am currently doing a cross platform software calling ffmpeg in c++ and I need a ffmpeg build working on both ubuntu 32bits and 64bits for the installer.
I also need this ffmpeg build to include librtmp, libh264, x11-grab, alsa, and mp3.

I tried to compile ffmpeg on a 32bits virtual box to have a ffmpeg build working on ubuntu 32 bits and 62 bits.

I used this guide to build ffmpeg :
https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

After compiling all the libs and ffmpeg himself, after installation using the deb files, ffmpeg is working perfectly on the 32bits virtualbox with all of my required components but not on my 62bits ubuntu.

When executing ffmpeg on ubuntu 64bits i got a message saying : impossible find the shared library libspeex.

Do you have any idea why I have this problem only on linux 64bits with the save deb files ?
Do you know a website where i could find an ffmpeg 32bits build with all the components I need (static if possible)?
I tried this website http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/ but the build is not including alsa...

I have a build for windows working perfectly, I downloaded the 32 bits static build on this website : zeranoe builds website for windows.

Thanks in advance for any answer.
Regards.

Benoit Brayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve my "problem" by compiling 2 specific versions (one for linux 32bit and one for liux 64bits).

That's working now perfectly but I will need to create a custom install script to select the good ffmpeg version in function of the system...

Benoit Brayer